# Discord.JS How to get emotes from an old message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to collect the number of emotes or reacts from a message sent 1 hour ago, how should I do that?
I want to make a command like $reacts  and the callback should be the count of each reacts from that message. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const msg = client.channels.cache.get('TheMessageID');
return message.channel.send(`This message has ${msg.reactions.cache.size} reactions.`);
```

Hope that was what you were looking for